# Yii2 Active Record 'with' relation not returning child data

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to YII framework and I am trying to use active record and ORM framework with it.

Three tables am having Please check the image

[image: Design]

And here is my code for Customer , OrderType and Orders

```
class Customer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'Customer';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'name'], 'required'],
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'string'],
    ];
}


 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCustomers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CollectorCustomerMaster::className(), ['CollectorCode' => 'CollectorCode']);;
}

 }

 <?php
 namespace api\modules\v1\models;
 use Yii;
class OrderType extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'OrderType';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'name'], 'required'],
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'string'],
    ];
}
}

class Orders extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'Orders';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'name','customer_id','order_type_id'], 'required'],
        [['id','customer_id','order_type_id'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'string'],
    ];
}


public function getOrderType(){
    return $this->hasOne(OrderType::className(), ['id' => 'order_type_id']);

}
}
```

And if I try to query orders with order type , order type data are not coming.Here is my code ,

```
   if (Yii::$app->common->checkRequest('POST')) {
            //if ($this->validateRoute('getCustomers')) {
                $coCollector = Orders::find()->where(['id'=>'1'])->with('orderType')->one();;

                if(isset($coCollector)){
                    $data2 = null;

                    Yii::$app->common->setCode(200);
                    $response = ['status' => Yii::$app->common->getCode(), 'message' =>'Success', 'data' =>$coCollector,'data2'=>$data2];
                    return $response;
                }
           // }

        }
```

If I run this , I am getting following results.

```
 {
"status": 200,
"message": "Success",
"data": {
    "id": "1",
    "customer_id": "4",
    "order_type_id": "1",
    "name": "Aptitude  "
},
"data2": null
}
```

How to get the OrderType data also ???
Please someone help me. I searched throughly in internet I didnt find any sample code.

Comment: You don't have any `order_name` field defined. Is this the same code?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Sorry , posted wrong output , Edited my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the OrderType relation in your Order class as `getOrderType()` function. So you can get OrderType data using this relation function. You can directly call this relation function on your Order class object like this

`$orderTypeData = $coCollector->getOrderType();`

Or you can use it in a simple way like below

`$orderTypeData = $coCollector->orderType;`.

Then you can put it in your `$response`. Please check this [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data) for better understanding.